# Tank tracks only move on one axis with constraints

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

Hi so I'm not sure if this issue has been solved in the past but I tried looking and couldn't find anything specific.

My tank's tracks operate fine on the X axis and rotate the way tank tracks do when the body rotates but the problem is the tracks don't move along the Y axis as seen with the gif:[image]

I'm hoping that I can get the movement of the tracks universal, but I don't really know how to go about it. If anybody can maybe help out I'll leave the blender file as well with it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rowHu9vNGvb2XvCR67tb4lXO_CvnBC7p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There's a tutorial on making and rigging tank tracks [here](https://youtu.be/FlpCAWgMwRs). The part about rigging starts at around 8 minutes in.

Comment: This was the tutorial I followed but nothing fixed the issue of the tracks not moving along the Y axis.

Comment: What you want is not possible, because the rotation of tracks doesn't depend on where the tank *is* but on where it *has been*, and Blender doesn't know where it has been, in the case of unkeyed motion, doesn't even keep track of where it has been.  See SE's auto-generated comment's link from my close vote to get a better understanding of why.  If you want the tank's track to auto-rotate, you need to define a path for the tank to travel, and then drive movement from distance along that path.

Comment: Oh well, that's unfortunate. Thank you for at least trying to find something to help. Maybe I'll have to look up another way to rigging tank tracks then.

Comment: Although I will say I can move the tank forwards and backwards and the track rotates and can keyframe it. I don't know if that gives you more information to work on. If you take a look at the file maybe you can get a better idea of what's happening. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @DBN13 I have taken a look at the file; I've also seen a lot of people *trying* to do this in the past, using techniques similar or identical to yours.  I think if you take some time with the answers at the linked question, it'll all make more sense to you.

Comment: Will do, I'm sure something will click eventually!